# Which trigger should I use for UWP app to be persistently in the background

Tags: c++, windows, uwp

I am trying to make a simple app that would work with the Corsair SDK to change the colors of my keyboard programmatically.  I've developed a simple one that uses straight Win32 API that uses a notification icon to hold the process and allow me to stop it.

I'm trying to make a UWP equivalent of the application using C++ as well.  The thing I am looking for is the appropriate trigger so that I can run it in the background as soon as I have it installed much like the "Mail" app that runs in the background and can create notifications (which I won't be doing yet).

Also I would like it that I don't have any forms (or at most have it integrated with Settings)

**However for now, I would just like to figure out which trigger should I use?**

I was thinking of SystemTrigger::userPresent and SystemTrigger::userNotPresent (to show a different lighting effects on my keyboard depending on whether the user is present or not).

The only thing different between the two modes if when the user is present, I will take in the keyboard states and read some user specific settings.

Comment: Seems like `userNotPresent` didn't work for me.  Actually nothing is working in my sample yet (which is the Blank C++ app with the background task registration, then again it's just my first time with Visual Studio after a few years so I had to try to remember how to do basic things like adding a file).

Comment: Just from your description, I think you chose the right trigger `SystemTrigger` -> `UserPresent` / `UserPresent`. When you say it didn't work for you, what did you mean?  You can't make your background triggered? Or this trigger is not suitable for your scenario?

Comment: Just trying to get the debugger to hit the break point. So far it is not hitting it.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging with event viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/debug-a-background-task)?